# VMware Workstation wont let me add memory

Tags: memory, vmware-workstation

When I attempt to edit the memory setting for my Windows XP virtual machine, The box is greyed out and I cannot make any changes. This is also true of attempting to move the slider.

Any suggestions?

You can see it greyed out for yourself here:

[image]

Comment: Is the VM powered on ? if yes, you have to shutdown it to modify Memory

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot change the memory while the Virtual Machine is powered on. Shut down the machine and you will then be able to use the box or the slider.

[image]

Comment: The VM much be completely powered off (if it's suspended you can't make the change).

Comment: Mine is powered down, it still shows grayed out.

Comment: Make sure it is `Shut Down`. You will not be able to change the Memory if your machine is only `Suspended` and not `Shut Down`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and below steps solved it.

1. Remove read-only attributes of the virtual machine folder and files inside.
2. Run the vmware workstation software as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

If the state is "Shut Down", see if you have lock folders or files in the VM folder.

If you have those lock files or folders, remove those files and folders.

The lock files have a .lck extension and the lock folders have .lck at the end of their folder name.